# the transconductance of cascade MOSFET IF channel length modulation is NOT ZERO

Tags: transistors, mosfet, semiconductors, kirchhoffs-laws, transconductance

What would the derivation of the cascode MOSFET transconductance in small signal analysis IF THE CHANNEL LENGTH MODULATION IS NOT ZERO, as most examples[image] for the cascode mosfet transconductance say in Behzad Razavi's book is when channel length modulation is set to zero, hence there is no "ro" on the cascode MOSFET and the input MOSFET

Comment: In the small signal equivalent model, how is \$r_0\$ connected? It connects between ... and .... Now add an \$r_0\$ for M1 and one for M2 and you have the small signal equivalent circuit for a cascoded common source amplifier. In my (old) book by Razavi what you ask is explained in Example 3.1.5

Comment: thanks ! finally figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at Razavi Example 3.15, calculate the Gm (overall trans-conductance), then multiply with Rout of the overall cascode circuit